# Why is JsonFormat.parser() not properly parsing FieldMask?

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I am trying to implement FieldMask in my APIs. When I tried it in spring boot it worked without any bug after I added following bean.

```java
@Bean
public ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
}
```

But in one of the older projects, we are using `JsonFormat.parser()` to parse Json. In this case,it is returning FieldMask in snake case.

So even though in API I am passing

```json
{
    "user": {
        "fullName": "Abc"
    },
    "mask": "fullName"
}
```

I am getting `full_name` instead of `fullName` as the mask after parsing the JSON. So the field mask is not working properly as I am expecting.

```java
User byId = userRepo.getById(id);
if (byId == null) {
    throw new NotFoundException("User not found");
}
User.Builder destination = byId.toBuilder();
FieldMaskUtil.merge(updateUserRequest.getMask(), updateUserRequest.getUser(), destination);
```